# Toggle hidden files on and off when using :Lex command in Vim

Tags: vim

How do I toggle hidden files on and off when using the Explorer commands eg. :Lex?

I don't wish to edit or create a complicated .vimrc file, but rather just use a one liner inside the Vim editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to toggle hidden files, from `:h pi_netrw.txt`

> The "gh" mapping (see |netrw-gh|) quickly alternates between the usual
>   hiding list and the hiding of files or directories that begin with ".".

also from `:h netrw-gh`:

> **netrw-gh netrw-hide**
>   As a quick shortcut, one may press >
>       gh
>   to toggle between hiding files which begin with a period (dot) and not hiding
>   them.

If you were using a plugin like NERDTree the equivalent would be <kbd>I</kbd> to toggle hidden files.